# Browser helper object not working properly

Tags: browser, windows-7-x64, ieaddon

Am working on adding addon to IE11 (64bit) in windows7 and followed the  below link

[Brwserhelperobject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350432/BHO-Development-using-managed-code)

Iam able to see addon in my IE manage addon's but, iam not able to see message box.

Can any one say what iam missing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the given link
**the following event is not triggered  some times due to this message box is not popped out**

```
webBrowser.BeforeNavigate2 += new
        DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(this.OnBeforeNavigate2);
```

so instead of using above event use the below code

```
 webBrowser.BeforeNavigate2+= WebBrowser_BeforeNavigate2;
```

which generates  a method

```
 private void WebBrowser_BeforeNavigate2(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object Flags, ref object TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, ref object Headers, ref bool Cancel)
{
```

//write messegebox here
    }